# How can I call specific entries from XML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

So i have this XML code

```
<book>
<bookname>book1</bookname>
<author>authorman</author>
</book>
<book>
<bookname>book2</bookname>
<author>authorperson</author>
</book>
```

and I want to be able to get the bookname using the author according to the author's name or vice versa and assign it to variable using JavaScript.
I am trying to avoid using server-side programming and want to use JavaScript only.
This is my first time posting here since I am a high school student that recently learned to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `XMLHttpRequest()` `responseType` property to `"document"`, `overrideMimeType()` set to `"text/html"` to get an HTML `#document` as `response` within `load` handler.

Create a function which expects a plain object to be passed as parameter, having either `"author"` or `"bookname"` property with value set to the `textContent` of the `XML` `<book>` element `<bookname>` or `<author>` to match. Iterate the `NodeList` of `<book>` elements and `children` `HTMLCollection`, check if `localName` is equal to `"bookname"` or `"author"`, and the `textContent` matches parameter passed to function, if true, get `parentElement` reference, use `.querySelector()` with either `"bookname"` passed if `"author"` is property of object parameter, or `"author"` if `"bookname"` is passed as parameter, return `textContent` of matched element, or `'"author of <bookname> OR book by <author>" not found.'`.

```js
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = "document";
request.overrideMimeType("text/html");
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><book>
<bookname>book1</bookname>
<author>authorman</author>
</book>
<book>
<bookname>book2</bookname>
<author>authorperson</author>
</book>`;
const getBookData = (books, {bookname, author} = {}) => {
  for (const {children} of books) { 
    for (const book of children) {
      const {localName, textContent} = book;       
        if (localName === "bookname" && bookname === textContent 
            || localName === "author" && author === textContent) {
          return book.parentElement
                 .querySelector(author ? "bookname" : "author")
                 .textContent
         }
       }
     }
     return `${author ? "book by" : "author of"} "${bookname || author}" not found in library.`;
}
request.addEventListener("load", e => {
  const html = request.response;
  const books = html.querySelectorAll("book");
  console.log(getBookData(books, {author:"authorman"}));
  console.log(getBookData(books, {bookname:"book2"}));
  console.log(getBookData(books, {author:"authorx"}));
  console.log(getBookData(books, {bookname:"book3"}));
})
request.open("GET", `data:application/xml,${encodeURIComponent(xml)}`);
request.send();
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm but now i want to expand my search methods, what I need to do is the xml code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  var text, parser, xmlDoc;  

    text="<book>
    <bookname>book1</bookname>
    <author>authorman</author>
    </book>
    <book>
    <bookname>book2</bookname>
    <author>authorperson</author>
    </book>";  

    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

    console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); //book1

    console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue); //book2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you :-

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var xml = "<xml>"+
            "<book>"+
              "<bookname>book1</bookname>"+
              "<author>authorman</author>"+
            "</book>"+
            "<book>"+
              "<bookname>book2</bookname>"+
              "<author>author2</author>"+
            "</book>"+
            "</xml>";

  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
  authors   = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("author");
  booknames = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("bookname");

  var bookname = searchByAuthor('authorman', authors, booknames);
  alert(bookname);

  var authorname = searchByBookName('book2', authors, booknames);
  alert(authorname);
  
  function searchByAuthor(author_name, x, y){
      
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          if(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue == author_name){
            return y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          }  
      }
  }

  function searchByBookName(book_name, x, y){

    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
          if(y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue == book_name){
            return x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          }  
      }
  }
</script>
```